# Problema con regresión múltiple en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Cuando realizo una regresión múltiple para luego testear la capacidad predictiva, los resultados salen como NA incluso en los p- values. En los foros dicen que se debe a un problema de multicolinealidad pero debo ver los resultados.

Este es mi código

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
regresion_agregada <- read_excel("C:/archivo.xlsx")
View(regresion_agregada)

df <- data.frame(regresion_agregada)
df$periodo <- NULL

modelo_agregado = lm(data = df,formula = ir ~ .)
```

El output es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Definitivamente tienes un problema de especificación en el modelo, pero es difícil de diagnosticar sin un ejemplo de los datos. Tu R2 es 1, dicho de otro modo, de alguna manera  ubicaste a las mismas variables del lado izquierdo y del lado derecho de la fórmula. Es decir, estás regresando x como una función de x. Tu modelo es determinístico (no tienen parte aleatoria) y R con razón se queja porque es un violación fuerte de los supuestos de los modelos lineales (independencia de X y y).

Comment: Si puedes poner al menos el resultado de `head(df)` va a ser posible ayudarte.

Comment: Eso no puede ser posible porque la formula que utilicé es                 modelo = lm( ir ~ . , data = df) es decir que la regresada es ir y los regresores son 18 variables.

Comment: Si puedes compartir un ejemplo de los datos que estás usando para el modelo será mucho más posible ayudarte. Así como está formulada la pregunta el problema no es reproducible.